# ngIf in ng-container inside mat-table

Tags: angular, angular5

I am new to Angular. 
I have a following problem: I need to display on a table only rows with status == "FINISHED". I understand why my code doesn't work the way I want, but can't get the right solution for me.

Here is the .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 import { TestCase } from '../test-cases/models/test-case.model';
 import { TestCaseService } from '../test-case.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-cases-view',
  templateUrl: './test-cases-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-cases-view.component.css']
})
export class TestCasesViewComponent implements OnInit {
  testCases: TestCase[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['testCaseName', 'testCaseDescription','id','created','status', 'xls'];
  constructor(private testCaseService: TestCaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTestCases();
  }

  postRequest(testCaseId: string):void {
    this.testCaseService.postTestResult(testCaseId);
  }

  getTestCases(): void {
    this.testCaseService.getTestCases()
      .subscribe(testCases => this.testCases = testCases);
  }

}
```

test-case.model.ts file:

```
import { TestCaseParams } from './test-case-params.model';

export class TestCase {
  public testCaseName:string;
  public testCaseDescription:string;
  public parameters:TestCaseParams;
  public id:string;

  constructor () {
    this.parameters= new TestCaseParams();
  }
}
```

test-case-params.model.ts

```
import { EditedVar } from './replacement.model';
import { FilterVar } from './filter.model';
import { OutputVar } from './output.model';

export class TestCaseParams {
  public appsCount: number;
  public algId: number;
  public product: string;
  public invokeConsolidation: boolean;
  public invokeProdStrategy: boolean;
  public filterVars: FilterVar[];
  public editedVars: EditedVar[];
  public outputVars: OutputVar[];
  public fromDate: Date;
  public toDate:Date;
}
```

replacement.model.ts:

```
export class EditedVar {
  public path:string;
  public value:string;
}
```

filter.model.ts:

```
export class FilterVar{
  public filter:string;
  public filterType:string;
  public filterValue:string;
  public varch:boolean;
}
```

output.model.ts:

```
export class OutputVar {
  public path:string;
  public alias:string;
  public type:string;
}
```

Here is the html file that works:

```
<div id="view-component">
  <h2>Test Cases</h2>

  *some code just don't fit in the question*

    <ng-container matColumnDef="xls">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Xls report </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let testCase">
        <button *ngIf = "testCase.status == 'FINISHED'" (click)="postRequest(testCase.id)">Make Excel report</button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is what I try to do:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="testCases" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container *ngIf = "testCase.status == 'FINISHED'" matColumnDef="testCaseName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> testCaseName </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let testCase"> {{testCase.testCaseName}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf = "testCase.status == 'FINISHED'" matColumnDef="testCaseDescription">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> testCaseDescription </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let testCase"> {{testCase.testCaseDescription}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf = "testCase.status == 'FINISHED'" matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Report Id </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let testCase"> {{testCase.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf = "testCase.status == 'FINISHED'" matColumnDef="created">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Created </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let testCase"> {{testCase.created | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf = "testCase.status == 'FINISHED'" matColumnDef="status">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let testCase"> {{testCase.status}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf = "testCase.status == 'FINISHED'" matColumnDef="xls">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Xls report </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let testCase">
        <button (click)="postRequest(testCase.id)">Make Excel report</button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

As you can see I don't want to display rows with any status that isn't equeal "FINISHED". For this code I get a following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (TestCasesViewComponent.html:6)

I understand that I need to place `let testCase` somewhere else, so it would be defined on the ng-container level, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: Can you do `getTestCases().pipe(filter(({ status }) => status === 'FINISHED'))`?

Comment: You can try setting the condition on the row definition instead, `<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; *ngIf="row.status === 'FINISHED' ? true : false"></tr>` so you evaluate if the field of the specific row has the value you need

Comment: @ExplosionPills, isn't pipe a heavy operator if I have many rows?

Comment: I don't understand how you're able to compile it, I don't see `testCase` object on your `ts` file, but an array of `TestCase` object, and in your HTML your mat table have `[dataSource]="testCases"` but you are trying to access `testCase`? Think what you wanted to do is put those inside your mat-row not the table headers?

Comment: @IvanS95 You cannot have two structural directives on the same element.

Comment: @Donvino the table will end up iterating over every data element anyway

Comment: @IngoBürk thank you for the correction, is that explained in the documentation? if so can you provide a link just to have the info

Comment: @penleychan added .ts files for understanding the structure.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I've managed to do that by just using filter without a pipe: getTestCases(): void {
    this.testCaseService.getTestCases()
      .subscribe(testCases => this.testCases = testCases
        .filter(item => item.status === 'FINISHED')
        )
      );
  }

Comment: @ExplosionPills could you post an eddited answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than do the filtering at the `mat-table` level, you can filter the array that you get from the Observable and assign the filtered array as the data instead:

```
getTestCases(): void {
  this.testCaseService.getTestCases()
    .subscribe(testCases => this.testCases = testCases.filter(({ status }) =>
      status === 'FINISHED',
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That error is because *`testCase`* is **undefined**, and in javascript accessing properties (like *`testCase.status`*) in an undefined object will always throw that error.

But the reason testCase is undefined in the first place is because `*ngIf` will be run **before** the method `getTestCases()`

You have two possible solutions:

1. Instantiate the object;
2. Use another *ngIf to check if `testCase` is undefined.

For example:

```
    <div *ngIf="testCase">
       <div *ngIf="testCase.status == 'FINISHED'">

       </div>
    </div>
```

In other words, you just need to be sure that `testCase` in not undefined when you access its properties in the `*ngIf`.

Comment: I have an array of testCase with the name of testCases that is defined on the page. So I need element testCase to be defined in ng-container or even table, for now it is being defined in <td> tag.

Comment: Yes but your testCase array will get the data from your testCases object that is created in TypeScript, which means that it’s in TypeScript that you define the object, not the page template, so you either give it a default value to bypass the undefined error or you check if the variable is undefined before you access the property. That way it will not be rendered at first but as soon as your testCases gets values through getTestCases(), the *ngIf will be true and it will work as you intended